# The 'pwd' command take much time cost after loading a big file(eg:40M)

Tags: bash

The following test shell code test at: centOS 7 with bash shell; The code contains three phrase; phrase 1, call pwd command; phrase 2, read a big file(cat the file); phrase 3, do the same thing as phrase 1;

The phrase 3 time cost is much bigger than phrase 1(eg: 21s vs 7s)

But at the MacOS platform, the time cost of phrase 1 and phrase 3 is equal.
    #!/bin/bash

```
#phrase 1
timeStart1=$(date +%s)
for ((ip=1;ip<=10000;ip++));
do
nc_result=$(pwd)
done
timeEnd1=$(date +%s)
timeDelta=$((timeEnd1-timeStart1))

echo $timeDelta

#phrase 2
fileName='./content.txt'   #one big file,eg. a 39M file
content=`cat $fileName`

#phrase 3
timeStart2=$(date +%s)
for ((ip=1;ip<=10000;ip++));
do
nc_result=$(pwd)
done
timeEnd2=$(date +%s)
timeDelta2=$((timeEnd2-timeStart2))
echo $timeDelta2
```

Comment: I have Centos 7 and bash.
If commented out the echo $content result ./ttt.sh 7 8, when you do the second measurement it is probably still echoing. I divided your procedure into 3 independent parts and performed: time ./tt1.sh; time ./tt2.sh; time ./tt3.sh gives the result:
real 0m7.320s
real 0m10.245s
real 0m7.416s

Comment: `nc_result=$(pwd)` is **always** slow. Use `nc_result=$PWD` instead.

Comment: BTW, `fork()` overhead isn't specific to bash -- it depends on your OS kernel, not your shell (except insofar as some shells -- ksh93 in particular -- are smart enough to not fork unless actually necessary, since the POSIX spec doesn't *strictly require* that the context created by a command substitution be out-of-process; that's just the easiest way to implement the isolation it calls for).

Comment: The word you seek is 'phase', not 'phrase'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slawomir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56839474/14122) has a key part of the problem, but without full explanation. The answer to [What does it mean 'fork()' will copy address space of original process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207918/what-does-it-mean-fork-will-copy-address-space-of-original-process) on [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) has some good background.

A command substitution -- `$(...)` -- is implemented by `fork()`ing off a separate copy of your shell, which a command -- in this case `pwd` -- is executed in.

Now, on *most* UNIXlike systems, `fork()` is extremely efficient, and doesn't actually copy all your memory until an operation is performed that changes those memory blocks: Each copy keeps the same virtual memory ranges as the original (so its pointers remain valid), but with the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) configured to throw an error when there's a write to it, so the OS can silently catch that error and allocate separate physical memory for each branch.

There's still a cost to setting up the pages configured to be copied to new physical memory when they change, though! Some platforms -- like Cygwin -- have worse / more expensive fork implementations; some (apparently MacOS?) have faster ones; that difference is what you're measuring here.

---

Two takeaways:

- It's not `pwd` that's slow, it's `$( )`. It'd be just as slow with `$(true)` or any other shell builtin, and *considerably slower* with any non-builtin command.
- Don't use `$(pwd)` at all -- there's no reason to pay that cost to split off a child process to measure its working directory, when you could just ask the parent shell for its working directory directly by using `nc_result=$PWD`.

Answer (score 0):

$() invokes a subshell. The 3rd command starts when the second command is running.